# Expectation of reciprocal of Poisson distribution to some power

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, poisson-distribution, random

Let $X$ be a random variable that has a Poisson distribution, with parameter $\beta$. Let $\mathbb{E}$ denote its expectation. Let $\alpha>0$ be an integer. How fast does the function of $\beta$,

$$ f_\alpha(\beta) :=  \mathbb{E} \bigg[ \frac{1}{X^\alpha} \boldsymbol{1}_{[X>0]}  \bigg] $$

goes to zero as $\beta$ goes to infinity? Is it the case that $f_\alpha(\beta) \sim \beta^{-\gamma}$ for some $\gamma>0$ which depends on $\alpha$? Or is the speed of convergence faster than polynomial?

Comment: Because $\text{Pr}(X=0) > 0$, those expectations don't exist.  Or are you considering a truncated Poisson?

Comment: I corrected it, thanks.

Comment: The expectation can be written as $\frac{\beta  \, _{\alpha}F_{\alpha}(\mathbf{1}_{\alpha};\mathbf{2}_{\alpha};\beta )}{e^{\beta }-1}$ where $\mathbf{k}_\alpha$ is a constant vector of $k$'s of length $\alpha$ and $_{\alpha}F_{\alpha}$ is the generalized hypergeometric function.  I'm not sure what you mean by "How does [the expectation] go to zero with $\beta$".  Do you want a plot of the expectation given $\alpha$ over values of $\beta$ or a function that is the rate of change for values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: @QuantumLogarithm Please provide all conditions for your problem and state the question clearly from the beginning.